# 1999 Accord EX V6 suddenly stalls while driving

Tags: honda, accord, stall

While driving, the tach and engine will randomly rev slightly and then drop to 0, stalling the car. Sometimes it just shuts off without rpms increasing. This happens with manual acceleration and cruise control.

Power steering goes out, the engine dies, but no check engine light appears. If I attempt to start the car immediately, it revs without turning over. If I wait 8-10min, it will start again; jumping it also works.

Things I have replaced attempting to address this issue:
· Battery
· Spark plugs
· Ignition control module
· Ignition coil

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'm sorry but I think we will need to clear up what "revs without turning over" and what "jumping it also works" means.

Comment: Absolutely: “Revs without turning over” = engine sounds like it’s about to start but never fully starts. “Jumping it also works” = when the car dies, I have gotten out cables and jump-started it just like what would happen with a dead battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else searching, this problem was solved here: https://community.cartalk.com/t/1999-accord-ex-v6-suddenly-stalls-while-driving/119683